# Azure Graph Api Wrapper Adds Parenthesis to Query Path Causing Error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a reasonably simple query

```
var client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
var groups = await client.Groups
                         .GetByObjectId(groupId)
                         .Expand(g => g.AppRoleAssignments)
                         .ExecuteAsync();
```

On the face of it this should work fine however the underlying rest cal fails with a `400` error code.

I've found the api call made is actually:

`GET` `/TennatId/groups/0030a565-96cc-4c72-ac9c-968213b32677()?$expand=appRoleAssignments&api-version=1.5`

I've removed the `TennatId`, but the group id is correct, but suffixed with `()`. The value I am passing to the api does not `()` on the end. It is being added on my behalf. Is this a known bug, or am I miss using the api? I'm using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 2.0.2

---

**Update**

I mistakenly thought i was on the latest version of the Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient. I've subsequently updated to 2.1.1 and I'm still seeing the same issue. Strangely if I don't expand the AppRoleAssignments the query generated is legitimate, but missing the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this issue. It seems that this SDK does not support to use `$Expand` after the method `GetByObjectId()`. If you want to filter to get the result, Please try below method:

```html
 var groups = await client.Groups
                         //.GetByObjectId("e98c4ce9-e256-42ab-a7cb-d888aefe822f")
                         .Expand(g => g.AppRoleAssignments)
                         .ExecuteAsync();


var group= groups.CurrentPage.Where(c=>c.ObjectId== "0030a565-96cc-4c72-ac9c-968213b32677").FirstOrDefault();
```